# jQuery :contains selector always triggering?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to work out what is wrong with the following code, it is output to all pages with a specific template.

When I navigate to /auth/remind, it redirects correctly to /forgot/. When it goes to /auth/check/ it redirects to /forgot/success/ correctly. However, if I goto /, it automatically chooses /?status=1, whether the .valign `<p>` element contains "#1", "#2" or nothing.

Any ideas what the problem is? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.pathname=="/") {
    if ($('.valign:contains("#1")')) {
       window.location.replace('https://website.com/?status=1');
    } else if ($('.valign:contains("#2")')) {
       window.location.replace('https://website.com/?status=2');
    } else {
       window.location.replace('https://website.com/');
    }
} else if (window.location.pathname.substring(0, 12) == "/auth/remind") {
    window.location.replace('https://website.com/forgot');
} else if (window.location.pathname.substring(0, 11) == "/auth/check") {
    window.location.replace('https://website.com/forgot/success');
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The object `$('.valign:contains("#1")')` is a jQuery instance which is always truthy value. It means that even if `'.valign:contains("#1")'` selector doesn't yield any result `$('.valign:contains("#1")')` will still be "true".

Proper way to check if selector matches some elements is to use `length` property of the returned object:

```
if ($('.valign:contains("#1")').length) {
    // ...
}
```